# while() loop for user input

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm working on setting up a `while()` that executes until the user enters an integer. However, the way I have it now, the loop prints the message `"Please enter an integer"` again after the integer has been entered, and then the program executes normally. Can someone suggest a way to make not print that message again after an integer has been entered? Thanks!

```
            System.out.println("Enter word length");
            if(in.hasNextInt())
            {    
                n = in.nextInt();
            }
            else
            {
                while(in.hasNext()) //this is the loop i'm talking about
                {
                    System.out.println("Please enter an integer");
                    if(in.hasNextInt())
                    {    
                        n = in.nextInt();
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        String c = in.next();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I changed it to `while(in.hasNextLine)` and now the message prints twice in the very beginning. So it doesn't solve the problem, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you  want user to enter int (or Integer) and repeatedly ask user until user enters int(or Integer). If so, try this:

```
System.out.println("Enter word length");
if(in.hasNextInt()) {    
    n = in.nextInt();
 } else {
         while(in.hasNext()) //this is the loop i'm talking about
         {

             if(in.hasNextInt())
             {    
                 n = in.nextInt();
                 break;
             }
             else
             {
                 String c = in.next();
                 System.out.println("Please enter an integer");
             }
         }
     }
```